# joomla mvc model results where ate they called?

Tags: oop, model-view-controller, joomla

I'm confused how to project models result in view in joomla 2.5

I have the controller which is initializing the model

```
class FrontpageMyComponentControllerItem extends JControllerLegacy
{

    private $id;

    public function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = array())
    {
        // Initialise variables.
        $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
                $this->id = $jinput->get('id');
        $cachable = true;

                $model = $this->getModel('item');
                $result_in_view = $model->Item('23'); //$id what I get

        // Set the default view name and format from the Request.
        $viewName = $jinput->get('view', 'item');
        $jinput->set('view', $viewName); 

        return parent::display($cachable, $safeurlparams);
    }

}
```

now how do I have the result in my view?

Answer (score 0):

In most components data (results) are being retrieved from *Model* by the *View*.

I'm not really sure why, but I guess it's to give more power to Views.

```
FrontpageMyComponentViewItem extends JViewLegacy
{
    /** @var  array  Data are stored here */
    public $items;

    public function display($tpl = null)
    {
        /** Retrieve data from Model */
        $items = $this->get('Items');

        // Check for errors.
        if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors')))
        {
            // Raise an error
            JError::raiseWarning(500, implode("\n", $errors));

            return false;
        }

        // Assign data, so layout can access these
        $this->items =& $items;

        parent::display($tpl);
    }
}
```

This is different than usual MVC implementations where *Controller* is retrieving data from *Model* and passing it to *View*.

If you'd like to see example of this in Joomla, look at [MediaController in Joomla 2.5](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/2.5.x/components/com_media/controller.php#L55).

Sometimes the *View* may not be necessary (output is in JSON) and then you may retrieve data inside controller and output it instantly using `echo` like in [search suggestions](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/components/com_finder/controllers/suggestions.json.php#L39)

There are **new MVC** (vs legacy) classes in Joomla, but core components still don't use them.